# How can I roleplay a character who's been lobotomized?

Tags: roleplaying, ability-scores, player-characters, starfinder

I am doing a Starfinder campaign playing a Ysoki technomancer who had a black market brain augmentation go wrong, resulting in a "unique type of emergency lobotomization."

I was lucky in my ability rolls, and got a 5, which I used as my wisdom, which is perfect. I do have a higher intelligence than I would have planned though, at 17, making this question useful: [Mismatch between intelligence and wisdom - how to play it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/799/mismatch-between-intelligence-and-wisdom-how-to-play-it/7173#7173)

What are some role-playing ideas to get across my brain alterations specifically? In my first session with him, this was hard to convey/get across. Whatever things I can do, they shouldn't be like low intelligence and I think it would be cool if my character had a unique sort of set of limitations and/or strengths related to it.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to rpg.se! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about our site. Unfortunately as currently written this question is very opinion based and is basically idea generation which is off-topic here. There are infinite ways you could play this and no clear why to choose which is better. If you can [edit] the question to have a more obvious correct answer it might be alright. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the goal of roleplaying is to have fun.

If you think of a roleplaying idea and it seems awesome and funny, then you should do it, whether your stats support it or not!  If the other characters laugh and tell you that's awesome, then you will know that you are roleplaying correctly.

On the other hand, if you think of a roleplaying idea and it seems annoying or boring, and you think the other players might be sitting there wishing you'd be done talking so they could get on the game -- then you shouldn't do that.

Some of your proposed ideas seem like they fall into that second bucket -- deliberately being annoying to interact with, because that's how you feel a low-wisdom character should be played.  I recommend against doing this.  :)

If you like, you could try having unusual speech patterns, like avoiding contractions or [avoiding the verb "to be"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Prime).  Most people might not notice this right away, but after a while they might get the feeling that something is different about your character.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have **the** answer but I have some ideas I'll post here myself:

- Confuse NPCs.

If a low wisdom individual could conceivably confuse two humans, why not simply take it up a notch by confusing members of different species entirely?

I can confuse RPCs too, by for instance referring to them by the wrong names, but this could easily annoy them and/or just look like a human error on my part and not on the part of my character.

- Bogus failed perception checks

With a -3 in perception, I should see completely non-existent things when perception checks fail. I could keep this limited to when, say, I roll a 3 or lower, yielding a 0 or a negative number. In this case, maybe I see my mother, or a dragon. Note that my GM may not like me coming up with my own results for a failed perception check -- but I can maybe convince my GM to do this type of thing for me if that's the case.

- Occasionally say gibberish

Perhaps 95% of what I say is reasonable, and the other 5% just doesn't connect. Like, "where should we go next" I can say "No, I've never been there. You?"

- Or just don't say anything at all sometimes

until someone taps me on the shoulder.

This is a decent starting point, but I still think it could be more interesting. When I read about real brain injuries there can be interesting things like inability to imagine the future. These don't lend themselves to roleplaying, from what I can imagine, but are more interesting and less comical in nature.